# Use Macbook Touch ID button to sleep/lock

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I'm not sure if this has been asked before:

I want to use the Touch ID button to sleep or to lock my 2017 Macbook Pro 13". I know there are other shortcuts for doing that, but I want to be able to use the power button as such... (I also want to explicitly use the power button, I know I can add buttons to the Touch Bar).

By now, apart from using it as Touch ID, I can only use it to do a hard-turning off by pressing during 6 seconds or to access accessibility options by pressing 3 times fast. I want to lock my mac by simply pressing the Touch ID button.

I can't believe that something like that is not possible, or at least configurable... If it isn't, is there a way to use it as another regular key in order to make a shortcut? (if I try to create a shortcut, pressing the Touch ID button does nothing)

I've seen that some years ago, pressing the power button during 3 seconds pops up a menu for choosing what to do, but that also doesn't work in my case. In [this Apple's tutorial](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25410?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) (recently updated) they also mention the possibility of doing that by pressing the power button, but again, it doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's amazing it's not like this by default.

Comment: Relevant: one of Apple’s documentation pages explicitly states that the button no longer acts as a power button. From [Use Touch ID on MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207054): “Unlike with older Mac notebooks, holding down Touch ID on your MacBook Pro doesn't display a dialog with options to Sleep, Restart, or Shut Down. You can find these options in the Apple menu.”

Comment: Probably they would introduce this as a new feature in a future MacBook.

Comment: It's astounding that they haven't made this configurable, given how many long time users would have upgraded and lost this functionality in doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Touch ID button to lock your Mac after upgrading to Big Sur.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I run Big Sur and the Touch ID preferences pane doesn't offer an option for **locking** my Mac. Can you provide a reference to your answer?

Comment: I just tested it and it works. Just a single click locks my Macbook Pro 2017

Comment: It used to. After the latest update, it no longer locks or does anything.

Comment: I have new Macbook air (M1) and latest version Mac OS. Touch ID button can locked my Mac.

Answer (score 29):

On my M1 MacBook Air, the following works: press Touch ID with any finger **not registered with Touch ID** to lock the Mac. Then press Esc to Sleep.

Comment: This. Lock with Touch ID button was working when Big Sur came out and then seemed to stop working after a Feb. or March update. It was this answer (using non-registered finger/fingerprint) that's doing the trick for me now. One push to lock the Mac is a great feature.

Comment: There is no other use I have for *pressing* the TouchID button than for locking/unlocking. Is there a way perhaps to configure my machine to just lock the screen if the button is pressed while the machine is unlocked?

Comment: Not the best option, but I always press the button in the corner (without touching the fingerprint reader), to lock the screen.

Comment: I thought that this was a hit-and-miss, as it didn't always work for me. But it seems that this DOES work, you just need to hold the touch ID button for a second or so using a non-registered finger (to prevent it immediately unlocking again).

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible.

From [this Apple Support page:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207054)

> Pressing Touch ID won't put your Mac to sleep. Instead, choose Apple
> menu > Sleep. You can also add a Sleep button to the Control Strip in
> the Touch Bar: Select View > Customize Touch Bar.

**WARNING**: this answer is not relevant since BigSur release.

Comment: So it does nothing. Got it.